# Cant find C drive in live boot

Tags: files, kali-linux, livecd

OK so i have a USB that i can boot Kali Linux in boot manager and choose the live option and it works well but when i browse for files (can't remember what its called) i don't have the other option (i saw if on a friends Kali) to access my C and D drive files. I have looked through there and cant find it. I have recreated the boot able USB many times but haven't come to a fix for it. All help is extremely appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux does not map drives the same way windows does, there are no C:// or D:// drives. Instead it uses the paths like `/dev/sd[a-z]` for storage devices.

You can list your drives by running in a terminal `sudo fdisk -l` which will print out something like:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 23E0BCFE-73E5-4702-BE8D-844C25A199D6

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    923647    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2   923648   1128447    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3  1128448   1161215     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4  1161216 234440703 233279488 111.2G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdb: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3C00E7B6-CD0C-4474-B2EE-FBABBBDB07C5

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624   5244927   4194304     2G Linux swap
/dev/sdb3  5244928 234441614 229196687 109.3G Linux filesystem
```

Here you can see I have two drive, `/dev/sda` with 4 partition `/dev/sda[1-4]` and `/dev/sdb` with three partitions `/dev/sdb[1-3]`.

In linux drives are accessed by mounting them somewhere within the root file system. This can be done with the `mount` command such as: `sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt` which will allow me to read/write to my windows partition by navigating to `/mnt`. You can unmount a drive with `umount /dev/sda4` (not `unmount`).

GUI file browsers are also able to mount drives but exactly how depends on which one you are using (most are fairly obvious, but don't always show internal drives). Generally in GUIs you will see the file system label rather than the device name. You can see a mapping of device file to filesystem label alongside their type with `blkid -s LABEL -s TYPE`.